# Azure Data Factory: How to update the condition value in Until activity to exit the loop

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have pipeline parameter, flag, which I am setting as false. And I have put a condition in the Until activity which says that it should loop until the flag turns true. But I am not sure how to update this flag pipeline parameter inside the until activity.

Inside the until activity, I have Web activity and then a stored procedure which is inputing the response of the web activity.

Update: 
Just to give the fuller picture. After GETting the data from the web activity, I am simply upserting it into a table using Stored procedure activity. And then take the 'next-page' link from the response and again GET the data and then upsert. In this way I go till the time I get no 'next-link' in the response. I am basically implementing pagination in the endpoint here.

Answer (score 0):

What I do, instead of a parameter I use a variable, which you can set to an init value while declaring it. After reaching your stop condition you can use a "Set Variable" activity to set it to a value that you expect your until activity to reach.

Here is the expression I use in the until activity:

```
@equals(variables('Done'), 'True')
```